# What should happen if My standalone java process will consume all heap memory?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I am running a java program with an Max heap size of -Xmx1024m , My java program keeps on creating new objects .

I can see the heap used so far by the process by the command :-

**jmap -histo:live 89038 | head**

```
 num     #instances         #bytes  class name
----------------------------------------------
   1:      34001134      816027216  java.lang.String
   2:      17000000      408000000  OOMError$Person
   3:           327       83085304  [Ljava.lang.Object;
   4:          6307         813232  <methodKlass>
   5:          6307         714344  <constMethodKlass>
   6:           428         498840  <constantPoolKlass>
   7:           398         313088  <constantPoolCacheKlass>
```

the total bytes sum has already exceeded the max heap size. My java application should have stopped .
å
Even Young GC and Full GC both have tried to run , but even they cannot delete objects since i am keeping the reference . My application should have thrown some error and should have failed , but it is still running , don't know how ?

What should be the expected behaviour in the case when a java program consumes the max heap memory.

Comment: When the JVM tries to allocate the new object, it will fail with an OutOfMemoryError. If you have a try/catch block in a loop and if you are discarding the Throwable or Error instance, then the program can, in theory run for ever. However you will not be able to create new objects.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to `new` an object, it will return an `OutOfMemoryError` exception. If you have this code in a try/catch statement, then the program can exit gracefully and tell you where/why this happened. Otherwise, the variable you assigned the `new` to will be `null` and will crash your program.

Comment: the reason is my program is exiting but not printing anything in output file , i have set system.err to an output file and after catching the exception it should have printed that in an output file.

Comment: "Otherwise, the variable you assigned the new to will be null and will crash your program." not quite what happens. The exception simply bubbles up the whole thread up to the default handler, which might terminate the application (assuming it's single-threaded / everything else is a daemon thread)